# How to define multiple paths for one handler in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I have been trying and searched online, but was not able to find a response. Is it possible to achieve the following using Serverless Framework:

I want to use the `get.handler` that has the code to the following definition for both getting one item and getting all the items. So:

- if I hit `api.example.com/items/` I retrieve all the items
- if I hit `api.example.com/items/1234` I retrieve item with `id = 1234`

```
 - get_items:
    handler: project/items/get.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: items/{itemId}
          method: get
```

**So far** in the `get.handler` I check `event.pathParameters? event.pathParameters.itemId : null` if the specific item exists and call some `getItem(itemdId)` function and if it does not exits I call a `getAll()` function.

If I pass the item id in the path it works, but when I make a request for `api.example.com/items/` I get the following error:
`not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header`. This means something is wrong in my path and I have to pass the item id to the path parameters.

**My question is:** Is there a way I can use multiple paths in the `- http:` area, or what would be a recommended way to solve this issue (just create two separate handlers) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to easily accomplish what you're looking for.
Firstly, a lambda function can be triggered by multiple events. You can add another `http` event to the array of handlers like so:

```
get_items:
    handler: project/items/get.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: items/{itemId}
          method: get
      - http:
          path: items/
          method: get
```

Alternatively, you could use the `{proxy+}` argument. You can read more about the various proxy methods [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/)

Comment: I hope there's a typo in this. "Firstly, lambda functions can have multiple handlers." then you show how to add another event to a single handler.

Comment: Yup, you're correct. It should read "Lambda functions can be subscribed to multiple events.". I've amended the answer.